# Javascript select checkbox checked count by "name"

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

after doing some research, I know that the checkbox checked count can be done by `$(input:checkbox:checked').length;`

However this selection is vast, as I have few groups of checkboxes within the same page differentiated by the "name" attribute

`<input type="checkbox" name="vms" onclick="SelectVms(this)" />V001<br />`

If, I want to select **only** the **checked count in this "vms" group**. How can i achieved that?

Anything like this? `var count= document.getElementsByName("vms").checked.length;`

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input[name=vms]:checkbox:checked').length;
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gqTqN/).